# OData Any and All with JayData or Breeze

Tags: odata, breeze, jaydata

OData supports [Any and All](http://www.odata.org/blog/2010/11/11/support-for-any-and-all), which helped me a lot in my previous project. Now I use JayData to avoid writing OData query strings, but haven't found results by searching for any() and all(). 
Is there any existing functionality or plans to implement it?

I checked Breeze.js, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard JavaScript `array.some()` and `array.every()` functions are compiled to OData Any and All operations, so the API follows the JavaScript terminology, to hide the differences between different data sources.

Detailed blogpost - [Using some() and every() with JayData OData provider](http://jaydata.org/blog/using-some-and-every-with-jaydata-odata-provider)

The [provider capability matrix](http://jaydata.org/tutorials/jaydata-api-features) show that these operations are supported only by OData provider.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated post: 11/25/13

As of Breeze 1.4.6, 'any' and 'all' operators are now supported.

See: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples

### Older post

For Breeze, we should have support for both **any()** and **all()** within the next two months for both our WebApi and OData providers.

Comment: Jay -- Were `any()` and `all()` added to Breeze?  I cannot find any documentation about them on the API section of the Breeze website or in the Breeze code.

Comment: Not yet... but probably coming soon after I finish the Breeze MongoDb adapter, since we need it there as well. thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Err, so Breeze will soon support MongoDb? Is there a link to this?

Comment: Hi @JayTraband, there is already support for `any` or `all` in breeze?

Comment: Not yet, but soon.... :)  Lot's of pending requests out there. Please vote on the Breeze User voice. https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/filters

Comment: MongoDb support will be released any day now.  We are just trying to put together samples and docs at this point.